# what does" they" refer in "they will be attractive to girls"

Tags: pronouns

> If boys drive a certain car, or use certain aftershave, they will be <strike>attracted</strike> attractive to girls.

In this sentence, what does **they** refer to?
Does it mean **boys** or does it refer to **certain car and aftershave**?

Comment: "They" refers to boys who will be more attractive if they use aftershave and drive a sports car. - that's a stereotyped  image of what girls like about boys.

Comment: They refers to **Boys who drive a certain car or use certain aftershave**

Answer (score 3):

The word *they* refers to *boys*.

*Boys* is the [antecedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)) of *they* in the sentence you cited. Some examples from Wikipedia:

> b. My eccentric uncle likes chocolate. **He** tells everyone to buy him
>   chocolate. - Noun phrase as antecedent
>
> c. Larry was helpful, and **so** was Kim. - Adjective as antecedent
>
> d. He arrived in the afternoon, **when** nobody was home. - Prepositional
>   phrase as antecedent
>
> f. Our helpers did it very carefully, and we did it **like that** as well.
>   - Adverb phrase as antecedent
>
> g. Fred works hard, but Tom does not **do the same**. - Verb phrase as
>   antecedent
>
> h. Susan lies all the time, **which** everybody knows about. - Entire
>   clause as antecedent
>
> i. Our politicians have been pandering again. **This** demotivates the
>   voters. - Entire sentence as antecedent

Answer (score 1):

"They" refers to "boys." Who is driving the car? Who is wearing aftershave? The attractive boys.

> If boys drive a certain car, or use certain aftershave, they will be
>   attractive to girls.

If boys (have or use attractive things), they will be attractive to girls.

So, if boys drive cool, red, sports cars, then they will be seen as attractive. Or, if boys smell nice, then they will be seen as attractive.

This sentence is basically an "if-then" statement - except it is missing "then" right after that last comma. If that sentence had a "then," then it would look like this:

> **If** boys drive a certain car, or use certain aftershave, **then** they will be attractive to girls.

So, you can break the sentence into those two main parts. The first half is the cause, and the second half is the effect.